# Can TCPDF output text as image natively

Tags: image, text, tcpdf, spam-prevention

TCPDF seems really powerful when generating PDFs.  As many things can be done directly in TCPDF, I wonder whether it is possible to convert text to image directly in TCPDF. ( or save the PDF in such a way, that certain text parts cannot be easily read by machines)

The goal is to have a kind of spam protection, by making it hard for scrapers to extract certain data from the PDF files without using OCR techniques.

I am able to create images from text in PHP and insert them into TCPDF, but doing this conversion directly in TCPDF would make it easier to handle the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

No, not as far as I can tell. I'm answering this question as tcpdf documentation is currently unclear and i wanted to know too.
fyi what I did is use imagick (straightforward once its installed right) to turn the tcpdf pdf output into an image:

```
// from tcpdf...
$pdf_out = $pdf->Output($pdf_filename, 'S'); // returns pdf string
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution($dpi,$dpi); // eg 300, 300
$imagick->readImageBlob($pdf_out);
$imagick->setImageFormat('pdf');    // for pdf use 'pdf'
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(60);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $pdf_filename . '"');
echo $imagick; // put to broswer
```