# How do you convert an a dynamically creaded pdf created with tcpdf in to an image using imagick?

Tags: php, tcpdf, imagick

This is what I have tried:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution( 300, 300 );
$im->readImage('pdf.php[0]');
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $im;
```

This is the error I get:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: no decode delegate for this image format `PHP' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562

So either I need to force Imagick to read the file as a PDF or... I don't know what.

How do I make this work?

Comment: A few things to try; first make sure that the path to your PDF is correct. Set the iteratorIndex to zero: $im->setIteratorIndex(0);. Make sure the policy for PDF is set to "read|write" in the ImageMagick policy.xml file, it probably defaults to "none".

Comment: You need your `pdf.php` script to output the PDF file first, then you can run your code on the PDF file that was created. If you don't want to save it as a file you can have TCPDF output the PDF as a string and then use `$im->readImageBlob($pdfString)` instead of `$im->readImage()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can TCPDF output text as image natively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047031/can-tcpdf-output-text-as-image-natively)