# How can i convert tcpdf pdf output into an image

Tags: php, image, pdf, tcpdf, imagick

I have a tcpdf script that generate pdf output and would like to convert this output result directly as image . i have already a convert script using imagick but this one works only if we have a saved pdf

Comment: Save it to a temporary file and then use the method you have working? I know there must be a better way without having to waste that file write / read cycle, but that might work until you find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49460767/653182